# Finding Maximum Determinant of a $6\times 6$ Matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

> What is the maximum possible determinant of a $6 \times 6$ matrix of $\pm1$?

This is the maximum I reached:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 & -1 \\
 1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 &  1 
\end{vmatrix} = 32$$

Comment: [Close enough](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465627/maximising-determinant-problem)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html

Comment: @IvanNeretin there is no 6*6 Hadamard matrix.

Comment: True, but still the link contains some relevant information.

Comment: random check (with excel) gave $\left|\begin{matrix}-1 && 1 && -1 && 1 && 1 && -1 \\
-1 && -1 && 1 && -1 && -1 && 1 \\
-1 && -1 && -1 && 1 && 1 && 1 \\
-1 && 1 && 1 && -1 && 1 && 1 \\
1 && -1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && -1 \\
-1 && 1 && 1 && 1 && -1 && 1\end{matrix}\right|=96$ (not sure if its maximum)

Comment: Update: Brute Force: Found one with determinant $160$, I got a feeling that I've hit the roof! The logic I used is pretty sloppy, I can't assure if that's it.

Comment: @JessePFrancis That is the best possible since it equals the [upper bound of Ehlich and Wojtas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem#The_Ehlich.E2.80.93Wojtas_bound_for_n.C2.A0.E2.89.A1.C2.A02_.28mod_4.29).

Answer (score 1):

**Another way to look at the problem**: you can write your matrix $M$ (say) as $M=A+I$ where $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix and $I$ is a diagonal matrix. Then $|M|=|A|+|I|$ and [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Determinant) the determinant case of skew symmetric matrix when $n$ is even.

Comment: $A$ is not skew symmetric if $M=diag(1,1,-1,1,1,1)$

Comment: Here by $M$ I am denoting the OP's matrix, not a general idea.